# Weird texture on "Material" mode (or GLSL Shading)

Tags: texturing, materials

Hi I am new to Blender.

Making a model and under "Texture" mode, it looks fine.(Left side)
But when I change to "Material" mode, it appears to be messed up. (right side).

How to fix?[image]

Comment: can you provide the material / nodes you are using here ?

Comment: Welcome :) if you wish, it's easy to share your .blend with a service such http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (permanent storage) to let others take a closer look.